# How do i get Word to check Integrity of my text?

Tags: vba, ms-word, macros

i want to automatically check my document for certain properties:

1. a space before a parenthesis
2. look for weasel words, that is specified in a list
3. Unprintable characters (I set a lot of equations and then changed the type - not good)

Ideally I would like word to marker all these with a comment, so i can fix them later.

Is this testing of text possible/feasible/already existing in word?

Comment: please improve your question (is it cut, unfinished?). It would be best if you enumerate all exact problems or show a picture of document. At the moment your question is unclear. There could be different technique needed for different kind of your problem.

Comment: thanks, i improved the question a bit.

Comment: the quickest and possibly best option is to use `find` feature of Word. There is option to mark all found ranges.

Comment: can this be automated somehow? so that i can run the whole suite at once?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't run it at once as it's not possible to highlight hidden document marks if you need some. Try this two subs for different goals (read some comments inside subs, too)

```
Sub Searching_For_Text()
    'will highlight all options added with .HitHighlight method
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearHitHighlight
    'words
        .HitHighlight "Variant" 'any word this way
    'any text
        .HitHighlight "  ("  'this for spaces before parenthesis 

    'partially specified text
        .HitHighlight "doc"  'simply this for words like: _
                            document, documents

    'option 2- this can't be highlighted but no error returned
        .HitHighlight "^p" 'paragraph mark
        .HitHighlight "^l" 'soft line mark
    End With
End Sub
```

And for special document marks:

```
Sub Searching_Special_marks()
    'for paragraph marks you need to search each separately
    'each time you call it you will find next one, next to current selection point
    With Selection.Find

    'some cleaning
    .ClearFormatting

    'searching each separately
        .Text = "^p"    '^l for soft lines, _
                        ^t for tabs, etc.
        .Forward = True
        .Execute
    End With
End Sub
```

I think you need to make some experiments with these possible solutions.

Comment: i like it ! can i inser comments instead of highlighting it?

Comment: if you want to insert comment you would need to go with second subroutine- find and do action...